# Greater Number to its left

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of numbers, for each number print the first number to it’s left which is greater than the current number.

Example
        
Input -> 5,3,2,4,8,6
        
 Output-> -1, 5,3,5,-1,8

> O(n) solution required

Comment: Did you need just O(n) algorithm? I think O(n ^ 2) is good for this problem. You need to have two nested `for` loop for implementing this algorithm and two nested `for` means O(n ^ 2).

Comment: O (n ^ 2) takes more computing than O (n) so  O(n) is needed.
O(n ^ 2 ) is simple a nested loop which can be easily done

Comment: this might be relevant to you: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/

Comment: Thanks for the link! However, description of method 2 on that page seems to be lacking details... For example, what about PUSHING next element to the stack? It never mentions that this needs to be done.. If we don't push next element then the stack will contain only 1 element (the initial one).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, O(n) algorithm is certainly possible. The trick is to use binary representation of numbers.

I will use your example to illustrate my algorithm. Lets imagine that we are working with 8-bit unsigned integers (for 32-bit or 64-bit integers the solution is essentially the same).

**INITIALIZATION STEP**

[image]

During the initialization step we'll build a boolean matrix from binary representation of the numbers. Such matrix can obviously be built in O(n) time. Also, we'll store currently found "bigger-on-the-left" number and its index (the bottom-most row of the table) in the array called "current bigger". So, each entry in this array is a **pair** `(value, index)`. It will be initialized with `-1` value (index is skipped for simplicity; it can be said that the value is `-1, None`).

**RECURSIVE STEP**

Then, we'll need to scan this matrix from top to bottom (most significant bit to least significant), from left to right. This will be done by function

```
biggerNumber(indices, bitNumber)
```

where indices is the list of indices we are dealing with, and bitNumber corresponds to the row of the table we are looking at. This function will be called recursively. The initial call is

```
biggerNumeber([0,1,2,3,4,5], 7)
```

Since all bits 4-7 are zeros, lets consider scanning bit number 3.

[image]

When scanning the table from left to right, the following cases are possible:

- `0...0` and `1...1`: in this case nothing can be said which of these numbers is bigger (need to look at lower bits).
- `10...0`: in this case the left number is obviously bigger than all of the right numbers. So, for all the numbers whose bit is `0` we can update the "current bigger" entry with the value of the number, whose bit is `1`, if the index of this number is bigger than that already stored in the "current bigger" entry (meaning that the newly found number is a closer neighbour than what was found before).

So, for bit 3 we can only see `10` sequence one - for indices 4 and 5. Thus, we update "current bigger" of index 5 (value=8 and index of that number is 4, thus pair (8,4))

Now, we need to proceed **recursively**. Lets recall the function signature:

```
biggerNumber(indices, bitNumber)
```

We need to break the list of indices into two: the first will include those numbers whose bit at `bitNumber` position is `0` and the second will include those whose bit is `1`. In our example, the two calls will be:

```
biggerNumber([0,1,2,3,5], 2)
biggerNumber([4], 2)
```

meaning that now we are going to look at bit number 2. Since the second call is trivial, lets consider how we'd deal with indices `[0,1,2,3,5]`:

[image]

We can see pattern `100` immediately, so we update "current bigger" for indices 1 and 2. Then, we'll make further recursive calls, based on the value of bit 2:

```
biggerNumber([0,3,5], 1)
biggerNumber([1,2], 1)
```

The next two steps are left as exercise to the reader. By following it through you will get the expected answer.

Now, the complexity of this algorithm can be evaluated as follows. At each step we break the original array into two. So, each number will go into one of those arrays. Because of that, during subsequent recursive calls, each number will be analyzed at most `totalNumberOfBits` times. Therefore, the complexity is `totalNumberOfBits*n`.

Once again, this algorithm will not deal with arbitrary long integers. It is based on the assumption that we can efficiently convert a number into its binary representation. But in most modern-world use cases (when the values correspond to "number of votes", "profile views", etc.) this is a valid assumption.

Answer (score 2):

int arr[] = { 5, 3, 2, 4, 8, 6 };
As suggested by [Next Greater Number](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/) reference thanks to @גלעד-ברקן , my below code

```
private void printPrevGreaterElement(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < 1) {
        return;
    }

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(arr[0]);
    int next = arr[0];
    int element = 0;

    System.out.println(next + " -- > " + -1);

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        next = arr[i];

        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            element = stack.pop();

            while (next > element) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                element = stack.pop();
            }

            if (element > next) {
                System.out.println(next + " -- > " + element);
                stack.push(element);
            } else {
                System.out.println(next + " -- > " + -1);
            }
        }
        stack.push(next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def next_great(seq):
    gsf = seq[0]              # Assign greater_so_far
    pe = seq[0]               # Record previous element
    seq[0] = -1
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):  # start from index 1 in array
        if seq[i] < pe:           # Check if you should exchange it with pe
            seq[i], pe = pe, seq[i]
        elif seq[i] < gsf:        # else exchange with gsf
            seq[i] = gsf
        elif seq[i] > gsf:        # else update gsf and assign -1 to seq[i]
            gsf = seq[i]
            seq[i] = -1
    return seq
```